# Appending Data at top in column

Tags: mysql

I am trying append the data the start of the particular row . I've written query for appending at the end of particular row.

```
update yourtable 
set yourcol = case when yourcol is null then 'a,b,c'
                  else concat(yourcol, ' a,b,c') end
```

How i can write for appending values at start of the particular instead of inserting bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to prepend new data on column data.

```
update yourtable 
   set yourcol = case when yourcol is null then 'a,b,c'
                      else concat( 'a,b,c', ',', yourcol ) -- add a comma as well
                 end
```